# Can I directly select colors on selected points in Illustrator's gradient slider?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

[image]

As you can see in this image, I want to select those colors and use them in gradient effects. Right now, I first select one color and copy the hex code, then paste it in the gradient.

Can I directly select colors on selected point in the gradient slider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps a lot to add colours you'll want to use in gradients to your `Swatches` panel (<kbd>Window > Swatches</kbd>) first. You can do so by dragging the colour from the tool box to the panel.

Then, with the `Gradient` panel open, drag a swatch over a colour stop to have its colour become the swatch's. You can also drag a swatch over the gradient preview in the `Gradient` panel to add a new stop with that colour.